# Why do I get a 504 Timeout in my ELB PHP session every 3 days?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, session, timeout, amazon-efs

The issue that I'm having is that I get 504 timeout from the ELB. This happens every 3 days. The time when it happen it's not when the server had the max current users.

This is the actual architecture:

HTTPS ELB that distribute the traffic in two instances.

- Idle timeout: 300

EC2 Instances had 5% of use, this are m4.xlarge.

We had the following values in Apache:

- ServerTimeOut 300
- MaxRequestWorkers 1000

And sometime we get in apache the next error but not always:

```
server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

In the slow php log we receive the next error:

```
script_filename = file_path [0x00007f05681bb3c8] session_start()
```

The session are stored in a AWS EFS. This EFS are mounted in the two instances, I checked cloudwatch to see PermittedThroughput and Burst but it's seems to be okay.

We have a Kibana running to get a statistics logs, and when the error happens the logs register from the same IP the same request every 100ms. The request is the same when at the time that the error occurs but it's different between the the errors that occurs every 3 days.

Do you think that is a back-end error or is it related with the architecture?